# MySQL convert ISO date to datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table with 20,000,000 rows with a column "time" that was saved as a string (type=TEXT), and contain values of 3 distinct forms:

- NULL
- DateTime: 2020-01-01 15:23:45
- ISO Dates: 2020-01-01T15:23:45.000Z

Is there a way in MySQL to convert all of the ISO Dates to proper DateTime format? When I try to cast them to "Datetime" the query fails. When I try to alter table, the query fails.
When I try to alter table, I get:

> Incorrect datetime value: '2020-02-13T08:10:02.000Z' for column 'time' at row 668290

I am aware I can query all rows from the DB to some other language, convert it there, and then update row-by-row, I just want to make sure there isn't an easy way to do it directly in SQL.

Comment: is `.000Z` always consistent across all (these) rows?

Comment: @Martin Yes, it is consistent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because `.000Z` is consistent across all related rows:

You can run the following query:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET `Time` = REPLACE (REPLACE (`Time`, 'T', ' '), '.000Z', '')
WHERE `Time` IS NOT NULL
```

This nested Replacement checks the TEXT column for the values and if found replaces them with the corresponding space or blank;

Therefore :

- `NULL` becomes `NULL`
- `2020-01-01 15:23:45` becomes 2020-01-01 15:23:45 (no finds to replace)
- `2020-01-01T15:23:45.000Z` becomes 2020-01-01 15:23:45

So the ISO becomes a DateTime shape, which you should be able to then seemelessly convert by changing the column type from `Text` into `DateTime`.

[MySQL Manaul - Replace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html)

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is a one-time data correction, so doesn't need to be automated and speed isn't a consideration.

Given that, I would start by altering the table such that the field is 19 characters long. This will truncate the unwanted `.000Z` elements from the ISO datestamp records.

After this, I would do an update query to replace the `T` character with a space. It's always at the same location, so something like this:

```
UPDATE mytable set myfield = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(myfield, 0, 10), ' ', SUBSTRING(myfield, 11, 8))
```

That'll update all records, but correct records should end up the same as they were.

Obviously, run this on a small sample data set first to confirm that it works before throwing it at your main DB. If the DB is large, it could take a while to run.

Comment: Good call with the string length to cut off that trailing `.000Z` .

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is also acceptable, but the other solution is a bit more intuitive to me.